# K5 configuration with common vertices in subdivided edges

Tags: graph-theory

Can a K5 configuration use the same vertex in the subdivision of different edges, eg in a K5 configuration I have vertex a connected to vertex d via vertex e as well as vertex c connected to vertex f via vertex e.

This question arises from the following :
[image: graph]

I have to determine whether the graph is planar. My current solution is using the the vertices a,b,d,c,f to construct a K5, but then a lot of the edges pass through vertex e, hence my question.

Also could a K3,3 also share a vertex in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not valid. If you could share nodes in that way, you would be able to prove that this graph is not planar (despite obviously being so):

[image: pentagram with nodes at the intersections]

---

Consider, however: [image: OP's image with an embedded K5]